# Height Media Queries not working properly on iPhone 6 with Safari

Tags: android, ios, css, iphone, media-queries

I have the following media queries which supposed to work in iPhone and Android in a Webview:

```
@media (max-height: 275px) {
  .logo {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-height: 365px) {
    .default-title {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 450px) {
    .logo {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 315px) {
    .logo {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}
```

Basically it is supposed to make elements shrink/disappear as workspace height decreases.

It works very well on Android devices, but is completely ignored on my iPhone 6. It's as though Safari is completely unaware that the keyboard is open. If that's the case, then I have 3 questions:

1. How to detect the keyboard opening/closing
2. It is possible to make these media queries work for both Android and iPhone?
3. Does this have something to do with the Retina display of the iPhone 6?

Answer (score 0):

Reorder your media queries form max to min:

```
@media (max-height: 450px) {
    .logo {
        padding-top: 1rem;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 365px) {
    .default-title {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 315px) {
    .logo {
        padding-top: 0;
    }
}

@media (max-height: 275px) {
    .logo {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't help. It just seems like the keyboard is an overlay above the webview so these queries will never be taken into consideration

Comment: @Tsury, yep, it doesn't work for keyboard. There is no way to react on keyboard from css as i know.